# Is MySQLdb a module or an interface?

Tags: python, database, mysql-python

From https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm

> The Python **standard for database interfaces** is the Python DB-API.
>
> MySQLdb is **an interface** for connecting to a MySQL database server
>   from Python. It implements the Python Database API v2.0 and is built
>   on top of the MySQL C API.

Is MySQLdb a module or an interface?

What does "an interface implements a standard for interfaces" mean? 
I can understand that a module implements an interface.

Thanks.

Comment: It means it rewrites the interface of MySQL C API to match Python DB-API which is the Python standard for database interfaces.

Comment: It's what they call an [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).